# How to pass list of integer from robot test case to backend java function or method?

Tags: java, robotframework, robotframework-ide

Robot Test:

```
${SomeList} Create List  70  30  50
```

JAVA Code:

```
@RobotKeyword
public void myJavaMethod(List<Integer> someList)
```

Here, Problem is thought you put type of list is in Integer, it interprets in String only. 
How to pass it as Integer List?

Comment: `for(String s : strList) intList.add(Integer.valueOf(s));` probably you need this!

Comment: this is something I want to avoid in java side. I am doing it what you mentioned above, but was trying to find solution for getting them as integers from robot only.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could convert the arguments from strings to integers within your Java method implementation, as suggested in the comments, or you could declare your list like this:

```
${SomeList} Create List  ${70}  ${30}  ${50}
```

This will effectively declare your arguments as integers.
This syntax is documented [here](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#number-variables)